# Запись ячейки с типом TEXT как переменной в SQLITE

Tags: python, python-3.x, база-данных, sqlite

Писал чат-бота, использовал SQLite, и вскоре нашел в нем ошибку. Когда записываю значения в базу данных подобным образом:

```
update users
set ... menu = "shoes" ..., shoes = "[2, 1, 2, 2]"
where id = 1
```

Возникает проблема, хоть тип ячейки `menu` текст, он воспринимает в этом случае текст `shoes` как переменную, и записывает вместо самого текста, значение переменной. Чтобы проанализировать проблему, использовал это:

```
send(f'''update users
set id = {bot_id}, nick = "{nick}", menu = "{menu}", ..., shoes = "{shoes}"
where id = {bot_idm}''')
```

На выходе получилось вот что:

```
update users 
set id = 1, nick = ".mlneko", menu = "main", ..., shoes = "[2, 1, 2, 2]",
where id = 1
```

При чтении из базы получился другой результат. Вместо текста `'shoes'`, в ячейке `menu` было записано значение другой ячейки `shoes`:

```
(1, '.mlneko', '[2, 1, 2, 2]', 30000, 1, 0, 0, 13, 50, 10, 6, 100, 980, '1', 1, 1, '[1]', '[1]', '[2, 1, 2, 2]', 1)
```

Код чтения из базы:

```py
def read(self):
    try:
        c.execute(f'SELECT * FROM get_id WHERE vk_id = {event.obj["from_id"]}')
        # У меня две таблицы, в одной аккаунты без вк айди, а в другом чисто вк айди и бот айди.
        self.isreg = 1
        self.bot_id = c.fetchall()[0][0]
        self.vk_id = event.obj['from_id']
        c.execute(f'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = {self.bot_id}')
        self.result = c.fetchall()[0]
        result = self.result
        self.nick = result[1]
        self.menu = result[2]
        ...
        # Чтобы вместо '[1, 2, 3]' был полноценный список.
        exec(f'self.shoes = {result[18]}')
```

база данных создавалась таким образом:

```
CREATE TABLE "users" (
    "id"    INTEGER,
    "nick"  TEXT,
    "menu"  TEXT,
    ...,
    "shoes" TEXT
    PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
```

Как исправить? Может менять базу данных? Какая будет наиболее приближенная к SQLite?

Comment: Приведите код на питоне, раз у вас стоит тэг питон. Приведите сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: нет ошибки, просто в ```menu``` вместо ```shoes``` записывается ```[2, 1, 2, 2]```, из-за чего программа некорректно работает

Comment: Это очень странно всё. Приведите нормально код.

Comment: Вопрос можно редактировать. То, как Вы привели в комментариях - читать трудно.

Comment: ладно..........

Comment: Код чтения тоже давайте. Сдаётся мне там может быть косяк

Comment: уверяю, нет. с этим сталкиваюсь во второй раз, в первый просто поменял значение и забыл.

Comment: я уже половину основного кода скинул, а вы все ещё не верите что ошибка не по моей вине?

Comment: Ну просто очень странная ситуация. А прямой запрос к базе, не из Python - даёт такой же результат? А если нужные поля прямо перечислить, а не `*` написать в запросе? А если только поле `menu` из таблицы запросить?

Comment: да такой же, я открывал sqlite browser и там все точно так же было, в menu было значение shoes

Comment: В SQLite (да и практически в любой СУБД) для обрамления строковых литералов используется одинарная кавычка `'`. Двойная кавычка `"` используется для обрамления имён объектов (переменные, поля, таблицы и пр.). Так что в выражении присвоения `menu = "shoes"` сервер воспринимает `shoes` как имя объекта. Среди объектов тоже есть приоритет - скажем, если в данной области видимости имеются одноимённые переменная и поле, то приоритет за переменной. Просто потому, что для поля можно добавить алиас таблицы, явно указав, что это именно поле, а вот для переменной такой возможности нет. `menu = 'shoes'`

Comment: не используйте  f-строки в sql. используйте параметры запроса!